# FFMPEG has not managed to vstack

Tags: ffmpeg

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with this ffmpeg line? I'm getting error:

Input 1 width 619 does not match input 0 width 618.
Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_vstack_3
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0

The width of white solid was set correctly to 619.

```
ffmpeg -i image_1.jpg -i image_2.jpg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=619x800" -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h)'[0max][1ref];[1ref][0max]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h)'[1max][0max];[2][0max]overlay=x=132[overl];[overl][1max]vstack" -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 -y combined.jpg
```

[View error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGUoq.png)
[ERROR with format=yuv444p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOwRl.png)

[Became gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuoTz.png)

Comment: Forgot about this. Give me a day for the original Q.

Answer (score 2):

Default pixel format for `color` filter is yuv420p, which only accepts even numbers, so ffmpeg is actually outputting 618 as width.

Use

```
-f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=619x800,format=yuv444p"
```

Comment: Thank you, Gyan. But it did not help much. After hitting "Enter" the system become 30% load for a long time. I placed the screenshot int the post.

Comment: You've made other changes to the command. Add -report and share report.

Comment: This is a bug. File a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org. For now, add `-frames:v 1` to the 2nd output as well.

Comment: Thank you! The second -frames:v 1 makes it work. Do I need to set yuv444p for other 2 jpg inputs, or rgb444 is better? I saw in the report that scale2ref interpolation is bilinear, Is it possible to change to bicubic interpolation?

Comment: Add flags=bicubic; at the start of filter_complex. No need to change image format.

Comment: The images became gray. I place comparison in the post. Gray when bicubic and gray when bilinear

Comment: Change yuv444p to yuvj444p

Comment: yuvj444p did not help. Only overlayed image became gray, the second image is totally fine.

Comment: I added "-pix_fmt yuvj444p" and picture became ok. "ffmpeg -i image_0.jpg -i image_1.jpg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=619x800,format=yuvj444p" -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h):flags=bicubic'[0max][1ref];[1ref][0max]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h='max(ih,main_h)':flags=bicubic[1max][0max];[2][0max]overlay=x=132[overl]" -pix_fmt yuvj444p -map [overl] -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 -y 0.jpg -map [1max] -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 -y 1.jpg -report"

Comment: But overall quality is not very good Can I make it better for jpg? Even with png I see small differences before and after. Interpolation is still bilinear in some places. Report - https://yadi.sk/i/OY4Ix2jvuLzqhQ

Comment: See overlay filter documentation, specifically format option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find anything useful in overlay filter documentation.

Comment: Even if I export to png the pixel colors become slightly different. How can I fix this? When I do the same thing in Photoshop the resulted images are the same (0 values in difference layout mode)

Comment: When I added vstack the first image became gray again... Need help.

Comment: Share your inputs

Comment: Thank you, Gyan. I added "format=auto" to overlay and problem has gone.